# Control+Copy Function

Tags: web

I found out that whatever I copy from this website its automatically adds "Read more:#link of the page"

http://www.djbooth.net/index/dj-equipment/review/pioneer-djm-600/#features

how can I do that ?

Comment: That is **unbelievably obnoxious.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excellent question. Here is a solution which seems to works : http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/add-a-copyright-notice-to-copied-text/
Let me know if that works in your case.